# Roboto font difference between macOS 14 and RHEL7

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fonts, headless, rhel7

I'm working on a visual regression system which takes component screenshot locally with headless chrome and during build inside a CI and compares both afterwards.

Nevertheless I've run in to a problem, where the font is rendered differently on my machine (macOS) and the CI (RHEL7).

I'm using google's Roboto font, which I've downloaded and created a `CustomRoboto` font-face to mitigate issues with locally installed Roboto.

This is the screenshot produced by my machine:
[image: macOS]

This is produced by the CI:
[image: RHEL7]

This is the diff:
[image: Diff image]

If you look closely the letters are tiny bit "higher" than on my machine.

I would like to keep the "truth" screenshot creation local than on a CI. But my best guess is to do it on the CI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macOS uses different font-rendering code than Linux, and both of them are not exactly ideal. On RHEL, the FreeType library is used, and its settings can be variously tweaked to achieve different results (even for individual fonts and font sizes). Theoretically, it should be possible to configure it to resemble the way macOS treats font rendering.

See [The sad state of font rendering on Linux](https://pandasauce.org/post/linux-fonts/) for some background and [How to achieve MacOS font rendering in Linux](https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/6b5ch8/how_to_achieve_macos_font_rendering_in_linux_in/) for one of the attempts. Note though that the font itself also influences the way different rendering engines display it, so what works with one font may not work with another.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I guess it is the right one, so I'm going to accept it. Nevertheless I'm going to move all the things to the CI, this solution is bound to break with more devs and different machines.